# Issue with array being generated via looped query results

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, loops, cursor

I have been looking/doing different takes of this code below:

```
public String[] getData() {

String[] columns = new String[]{ app_name, app_location, app_dateTime};
Cursor c = myDatabase.query(app_table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

int iName = c.getColumnIndex(app_name);
int iLoc = c.getColumnIndex(app_location);
int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(app_dateTime);


String[] appointments = new String[c.getColumnCount()];
int j = 0;
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
    appointments[j] = " Appointment Name: " + c.getString(iName) + " \n Location: " + c.getString(iLoc) + " \n Date: " + c.getString(iDate) + " \n\n ";
     j++;
    }
return appointments;

    }
}
```

basically the objective of this code is for my query results to be fed into an array and then be accessed in a ListView in another class through the "return appointments" section of the code. For some reason my code does not seem to work and I cannot quite put my finger on it, I have tried loops in loops I have tried dulling the code down and then expanding on what I can get to work, but none of it is giving me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize and thank the people who submitted answers, I have figured out what the issue was, it was in another java class of mine. The loop listed above is fully functional so if someone was to needing to find a piece of code that would do what's asked above, then look no further.

Answer (score 1):

I think that instead of

```
String[] appointments = new String[c.getColumnCount()];
```

you need to use

```
String[] appointments = new String[c.getCount()];
```

`getColumnCount()` returns the number of columns (which is constantly 3 -name, location, dateTime-), and you need the number of rows there.

Comment: my apologies, I failed to mention that I have also tried changing

String[] appointments = new String[c.getCount()];

to:

String[] appointments = new String[99];

for the sake of trial and error. I believe the error is some where's in the for loop itself but I just cannot find it.